# Using array in cypress

Tags: arrays, cypress

How do use an array in Cypress? I try to extract excel data to JSON and stored it in an array so far the procedure works but when I try to call the array I used before it is not working well

Here is the screenshot:

[image: excelExtraction.spec.js]

[image: index.js]

[image: Result]

Comment: It may be happening due to the asynchronous behavior of JS, the last two log statements are run even before `cy.task`. How about you move all the `cy.log` statements inside `cy.task`?

Comment: the intention for this is to reuse the array for later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cy.log()` statements run after the task, but they take their value before the task starts running.

- cy.log(dataList) - `dataList` is a reference to the outer array, it's contents are evaluated at time of printing.
- cy.log(dataList[1]) - evaluates `dataList[1]` before the task
- cy.log(dataList.length) - evaluates `dataList.length` before the task

The data should be accessed in an async callback to be sure you see the correct values.

Some examples

```js
cy.task("generateJsonFromExcel", ...)
  .then((user) =>
    const dataList = [];
    ...
    return dataList;
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(dataList)
    cy.log(dataList[1])
    cy.log(dataList.length)
  })
```

or alias the result

```js
cy.task("generateJsonFromExcel", ...)
  .then((user) =>
    const dataList = [];
    ...
    return dataList;
  })
  .as('dataList')

cy.get('@dataList').then(() => {
    cy.log(dataList)
    cy.log(dataList[1])
    cy.log(dataList.length)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call your task in a `before()`

```js
describe('testing with dataList', () => {

  let dataList = [];

  before(() => {
    cy.task("generateJsonFromExcel", { excelFilePath, excelSheetName })
      .then((users) => {
        dataList = [...users].map(user => user.Email)
      })
  })

  it('logs the loaded dataList', () => {
    
    cy.log(dataList)
    cy.log(dataList[1])
    cy.log(dataList.length)
  })
```